# Possible to get 4 numbers at once with randint()?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, random, pytest

I tried to choose 4 numbers in `range(1,6)` using `randint`. And I did it using `for` loop. But after that I have to write python pytest tests. So I got the problem because after assertion using monkeypatch instead of getting for example `[1,2,3,4]` I got `[[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]`.

So I want to ask if is possibility to choose 4 items at the same time instead of using `randint` 4 times.

```
def throw_a_cube():
    a = []
    for x in range(4):
        x = randint(1, 6)
        a.append(x)
    return a
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make sure to include all the code needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You would need to just return `x` and then *call* `throw_a_cube()` four times.

Comment: don't assign the `randint` result to `x`, which is your loop variable. I suspect assigning to the loop variable hasn't worked and has failed silently. Use another variable, e.g. `num` to hold the randint then `a.append(num)`

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's possible to pick four at once. If you're looking to get four different numbers, your code should look more like this:

```
import random

def throw_a_cube():
    a = []
    throws = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for x in range(4):
        x = random.choice(throws)
        a.append(x)
        throws.remove(x)
    return a
```

Comment: I know, but you have still loop so I will get my assertion 4 times instead of 1.

Comment: Maybe It is possible to do it with different random like choice etc?

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure. Why is the assertion a problem?

Comment: I did it. Assertion problem was because for every randint it changes it with monkeypatch. Instead of randint I use a= [1,2,3,4,5,6] choices(a, k=4).

Comment: @New_stud If these asserts are a problem, you should mention it in the question and include a [mre] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comprehension:

```
import random

def throw_a_cube():
    return [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this suitable?

```
from random import choices

throw_a_cube = lambda k: choices(range(1, 6), k=k)
```

Comment: why use a lambda? Simple function def would be preferable surely

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself using for loops in Python, there's
usually a better way. Probably the simplest in this case is:

```py
from random import choices

def throw_a_cube():
    return choices(range(1, 6), k=4)


print(throw_a_cube())
```

Result:

```
python 4numbers.py
[2, 5, 1, 5]
```